# How to trigger a method on serverSessionTimeout in IBM Mobilefirst

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

My requirement is, I want to logout the user after 3 minutes of inactivity whether the app is in background or foreground.

In worklight.properties,

```
mfp.session.independent=false

mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession

serverSessionTimeout=3
```

In main.js, for the session timeout when the app is in foreground, I have set

```
WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval(-1);
```

Now, the application perfectly logging out, but once the app is logged out i want to show the user that session is timed out.

Is there any method available in Mobilefirst which will be triggered on session time out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature to handle this. You need to write custom logic. For example, have some flag stored in the localstorage of the application and store in it what was the last way the user logged in, due to actively tapping the logout button, and if not... it means it was due to  a session timeout.

Lets say, create a variable called `activelyLoggedOut`. By default `false`.

1. The user logs in...
2. Some time has passed... a request is made. The session expired. When the challenge is received then in the challenge handler you check for the value of `activelyLoggedOut`, if it's `false` you know that it's because of session expiration - output the relevant message.
3. or, the user taps "logout". Before logging out, change the value to "true",